# mIRC Read command not performing

Tags: mirc

I am writing an mIRC script for a bot account to read a random line of text from a text file when a user keys in !read. As of now, when any user types !read, absolutely nothing happens. I have other commands set to work on TEXT commands, but this one seems to be the most puzzling, as I'm referencing a document rather than putting everything into the script itself.

```
on *:TEXT:!text:#: {
  $read(C:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\8Ball.txt,n)
}
```

My file is titled 8Ball.txt. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: First, your trigger is `!text`... So nothing really happens when users type `!read`. Second, you just read the line, but do nothing with it, try adding `//echo -a` in front of your read.

Comment: I've replaced !text with !read...that was embarassingly simple.

Adding the echo  didn't seem to make a difference though.

<code>on *:TEXT:!read:#: {
  //echo -a
  $read("8Ball.txt",n)
}</code>

Comment: I receive an error:

* /echo: insufficient parameters (line 2, Read)

When the line is |  /echo -a $read(C:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\8Ball.txt,n)

Comment: Got it.  

echo -a $read(C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\8Ball.txt,n)

Changing the directory ended up doing it...it wasn't liking the location for some reason...I either blame me putting a / in front of echo, or I blame the space in Program Files (x86)

Denny you're fantastic.

Comment: Cool, maybe mIRC did not have permission to read the file so it failed

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
echo -a $read(C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\8Ball.txt,n)
```

Changing the directory ended up doing it...it wasn't liking the location for some reason...I either blame me putting a / in front of echo, or I blame the space in Program Files (x86)

Answer (score 0):

Your best move is to use the relative mIRC dir identifier `$mircdir` combing it with `$qt` which adds enclosing quotes.

```
$qt($+($mircdir,8Ball.txt))
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\8Ball.txt"
```

This way, you won't need to wonder why the script break when you changed the mIRC directory a year after.